# Passing Formik input values in nested forms using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

I'm currently having problems when using Formik with MaterialUI forms. Specifically,
I am having trouble passing Formik input values in nested forms using Material UI and having a small issue where `Formik.handleChange` is changing the value from number to string.

I have multiple forms that are split with Stepper component in Material UI. Since I am still learning, I tried to wrap Formik on one of the steps (later on I am going to wrap the whole stepper). Here's how it looks:

```
          {activeStep === 0 && (
            <Formik
              initialValues={initialValues}
              validationSchema={validationSchema}
              onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                  setSubmitting(false);
                }, 400);
              }}
            >
              {formik => (
                <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                  <div className="col-xl-6">
                    <Portlet fluidHeight>
                      <PortletHeader title="Incident Type" />
                      <PortletBody>
                        <IncidentSelect formik={formik} />
                      </PortletBody>
                    </Portlet>
                  </div>
                </form>
              )}
            </Formik>
          )}
```

The problem is inside the IncidentSelect form, Formik `handleChange` does not seem to change the selected `radioButton`. When I inspected with React Developer Tools in Chrome it seems that `Formik.handleChange` is changing the value from 0 to "0". How do I fix this?

Also, following the [tutorial](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/tutorial), I'm unsure how I can abstract my components? Note that DateTimePicker is using [material-ui/pickers](https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/). I'm not sure how I am going to pass the value to Formik.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
function IncidentSelect(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("female");
  const handleRadioChange = e => {
    console.log(props.formik.getFieldProps("incidentType"));
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FormControl component="fieldset">
        <FormLabel component="legend" required>
          Incident Type:
        </FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup
          aria-label="Incident Type"
          name="incidentType"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleRadioChange}
          {...props.formik.getFieldProps("incidentType")}
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            value={0}
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Injury To Guest"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            value={1}
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Injury To Worker"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            value={2}
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Incident / Accident"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            value={3}
            disabled
            control={<Radio />}
            label="OSH / Kids Camp"
          />
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
      <DateTimePicker
        label="Signed Date"
        variant="outlined"
        className={classes.margin}
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [tutorial](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/tutorial), it is easier to abstract the component that you want to use. Giving you chances to reuse them later in your application and more readable code.

Formik provides you with `useFields` API to get the props of the field via hooks. `useFields` is looking for the `name` props of your component to find the corresponding field.

Thus `RadioGroup` from MaterialUI can be extracted as follows:

```
export const IncidentRadioButton = ({ options, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  return (
    <>
      <RadioGroup {...field} {...props}>
        {options.map((option, index) => (
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Radio />}
            label={option.name}
            value={option.value}
            key={index}
          />
        ))}
      </RadioGroup>
      {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
        <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
```

Then you can use the `options` prop to put your data accordingly